# PHP Expire Time Variable

Tags: php, json, flickr

I am working with a Flickr feed and I am struggling to figure out why it will not update. I am lead to believe the JSON output is not being updated due to the expire time variable defined, though I am not the best with PHP and JSON just yet. Below is a snippet of the PHP file I am working with the generate the JSON file. I am looking for assistance in understanding each of the variables and the IF statement that follows. There was additional code that I omitted because I believe it isn't necessary to the particular problem. Thank you!

```
    $file = $cacheDir.'flickr_feed.html';
    $current_time = time();
    $expire_time = .05 * 60 * 60;
    $file_time = filemtime($file);

    if(file_exists($file) && ($current_time - $expire_time < $file_time)) {
        echo $file." is not older than $expire_time seconds, no re-cache<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Recached '.$file.'<br>';}
```

Comment: you have `.05`....

Comment: I don't understand, sorry...can you provide more detail?